# Regular expression with out the substring bab or abb?

Tags: regular-languages, finite-automata, regular-expressions

I'm having a problem coming up with a regular expression for a language L = {a,b} with out the substring bab or abb? 
I can come up with the one for just one substring, like

a*(b* aaa* )* b* a* to eliminates the bab and b*(a+ab)* to eliminates the abb substrings.

But putting them together is a huge animal :(

Comment: You can always construct an NFA and convert it into a regular expression. You can first construct an NFA for all words *containing* bab or abb, then make it into a DFA, then complement it, then convert it into a regular expression.

Comment: Think of what string could precede $b$. For example, what could precede $bb$? In this way, try to come up with "building blocks" for strings not containing bab and abb.

Comment: "But putting them together is a huge animal" -- How do you "put together" regular expressions?

Comment: @Raphael we "put together" by concatenation, intersection, and union.

Comment: @fade2black I am not aware of a canonical regular expression operation that provides intersection.

Answer (score 2):

There are a couple tricks required to get this right.

First, this particular problem is a lot easier if you approach it backwards, starting at the end of the sting.

`(abb,bab)` is an exhaustive list of all the cases in which `b` is preceded by 2 different letters.  If you want to exclude these cases, you just have to ensure that `b` is preceded by less than 2 letters, or a double letter.

Second, notice that these rules imply that if there are 2 `b`s in a row, then they must be preceded by `b` all the way to the start of the string.  Otherwise the second-to-first `b` will be preceded by `ab`.

Working from the end, then, we can have a free mixture of `a` and `aab`, and then there are only a few ways to get to the beginning of the string when we encounter a `b` outside of that pattern:

```
(ab|b*)(aab|a)*
```

Answer (score -3):

Thanks for the help, i came up with a solution, although I'm not 100% sure:

0*(1+000*)0*+(1*0*)

Here can use jflap to test a few strings.

[image: JFLAP]

Comment: If you're not sure you're correct, try proving that you are. Alternatively, you can construct a DFA for the language along the lines of my comment to the post, take the symmetric different with a DFA generated from you regular expression, and verify that the resulting DFA accepts no string.